# Adding metadata to the Android Account/AccountManager

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have login working using the AccountManager code, but by default the Account only stores the username and password. I also need to store the user's name, email, and some other data.

How do I go about storing this additional metadata with the Account via the AccountManager? It's also ok if this data is loaded each time the user logs in - do I add the additional params to a Bundle? If so, which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add and store metadata, use AccountManager.getUserData and AccountManager.setUserData.